# After send mail clear names, set em empty

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, normally I work with ASP.NET.

I have some variabels in a form, when I send the form I want to clear the variables/empty em.

I have tried the following..

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$navn, $telefon, $beskrivelse, $mvalue, $kommentar = "";
```

But that give me an error about the `$navn, $telefon, $beskrivelse, $mvalue, $kommentar = "";` so my question is, how do I clear the variables after I have run the `mail(...)`

Comment: Read the manual: `unset()`

Comment: i dont know how you do it in asp but in php: `$navn = $telefon = $beskrivelse = $mvalue = $kommentar = "";` check out barmars answer, that should help you

Comment: PHP doesn't have the concept of a `VIEWSTATE`, so probably you don't need to clear them anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set multiple variables to the same value, do:

```
$navn = $telefon = $beskrivelse = $mvalue = $kommentar = "";
```

In PHP, the value of an assignment is the value that was assigned, so you can use it as an expression in another assignment and they'll get the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Try equal to sign instead of comma

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$navn=$telefon=$beskrivelse=$mvalue=$kommentar = "";
```